# Generic database update method in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am looking to create a method that will be able to **update** any table in a database, given any number of columns to update as well as any number of fields to look up for (in where clause). The problem is that i cannot find a design pattern of such function that will be able to do that. How am i gonna send the parameters? It looks like i'm going to need two params[] which is not possible and sending the query string itself is out of the question. The method should be able to process any query like this:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Col1] = 1, [Col2] = 2, ... WHERE [Col10] = 1 AND [Col11] = 2, ...
```

As an example for a generic Insert method i have used multiple overloads of the same function with different object type as its parameter.

```
public void Insert(Broadcast obj){...}
public void Insert(Comments obj){...}
public void Insert(Seated obj){...}
```

Now this is simple since depending on the type of object, i am inserting into the respective database table the values taken from the object obj. Can't figure out one for an update.

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not just write separate insert statements for each table since they're all going to be different anyways?

Comment: Not that I would recommend the approach you are taking, but if you must, why not just pass something like a List<MyColumnDefinition> where MyColumnDefinition containts the column name/value etc?

Comment: This is exactly why the normal pattern is each different object type should have its own data access object (DAO) to perform CRUD operations on it.

Comment: Something you can do is an abstract base object with an abstract method to be implemented in each derived class and just 1 insert with that abstract base object as a parameter. Then, you can call the abstract method and by polymorphism each object will return or do anything you want

Comment: @mason I did this and sql query strings are all over the place. It's a mess! I don't like it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, but if I had to do it I would probably send the method an object from this class:

```
class UpdateStatement {
    public string TableName {get;set}
    public Dictionary<DataColumn, object> SetColumns {get;set;} // the object is the value to be updated
    public Dictionary<DataColumn, object> WhereColumns {get;set;} // the object here is the value that the column will be tested against in the where clause. 
}
```

and have it return the rowcount of the update statement as int